# How to inject code to a class without using inheretance?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using **WPF** with **MahApps Metro controls**.

I have created a base class for all my Window classes, that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public class WindowBase : MetroWindow,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanging(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangingEventHandler handler = PropertyChanging;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    /* code ommited */
}
```

And I want to use it in my Window classes like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : WindowBase
```

My XAML code to use MahApps MetroWindow:

```
<controls:MetroWindow ...
```

Which causes the following error:

> Partial declarations of 'MainWindow' must not specify different base classes  MainWindow.xaml.cs

So in order to use the INPC implemetations, in all my classes I need to find a way to inject those code to Window calsses in a way other that direct inheretance. Any ideas?

Comment: This is wrong. `INotifyPropertyChanged` does not belong into `DependencyObject`s. `DependencyObject`s have their own mechanism for property change notification (`DependencyProperty`). Create a proper ViewModel instead.

Comment: @Shabgard - Static classes are sealed. You cannot inherit from it.

Comment: @RohitVats It was a typo sir.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here.  If your view is `WindowBase`, then declare it in XAML as `<my:WindowBase ...`.

Comment: @HighCore I'm using code behind, why should I create a ViewModel. And how to use it in my code behind?

Comment: @Shabgard leave code behind alone. Code behind in WPF is intended to be used for `Animation`s, `Focus` and other UI-specific concerns. `INotifyPropertyChanged` has nothing to do with any of that.

Comment: @McGarnagle that works! Thanks. I was doing it wrong. But still is there a way to inject some code to my class without inheretance?

Comment: @HighCore you're right. But I'm still a WPF noobie and MVVM is a bit too complicated for me right now.

Comment: please search using your search engine of choice: "Fody notify property changed".

Comment: What do you mean "inject some code"?  Typically you would have to do that when the view instance is created, and that varies by how your app is set up.

Comment: I didn't find a better word for it. What I mean is, to reuse the code from another in my class like what happens in inheretance. The child get all the features of the parent class. If I have a conceptual mistakes in my question please inform me about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code behind is partial declaration of your View** and as evident from the error, *you cannot specify different base classes for partial declaration of class*.

In code behind you are deriving it from `WindowBase` and in xaml you are declaring it to be `MetroWindow`.

View declaration should be like `<local:WindowBase..` where local will be namespace where WindowBase is declared ofcourse.